# Opencart mysql db return affected rows count

Tags: php, opencart

How could I modify the opencart class so that it returns the [affected row count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)?

```
<?php
final class MySQL {
    private $link;

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
        if (!$this->link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);
        }

        if (!mysql_select_db($database, $this->link)) {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not connect to database ' . $database);
        }

        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->link);
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->link);
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8", $this->link);
        mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE = ''", $this->link);
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        if ($this->link) {
            $resource = mysql_query($sql, $this->link);

            if ($resource) {
                if (is_resource($resource)) {
                    $i = 0;

                    $data = array();

                    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
                        $data[$i] = $result;

                        $i++;
                    }

                    mysql_free_result($resource);

                    $query = new stdClass();
                    $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
                    $query->rows = $data;
                    $query->num_rows = $i;

                    unset($data);

                    return $query;  
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->link) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->link) . '<br />' . $sql);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    public function escape($value) {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysql_real_escape_string($value, $this->link);
        }
    }

    public function countAffected() {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysql_affected_rows($this->link);
        }
    }

    public function getLastId() {
        if ($this->link) {
            return mysql_insert_id($this->link);
        }
    }   

    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->link) {
            mysql_close($this->link);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Example usage:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "category SET image = '" . $this->db->escape(html_entity_decode($data['image'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')) . "' WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "'");

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description SET category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "'");

$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$data['parent_id'] . "' ORDER BY `level` ASC");
```

Comment: It would be much easier if they hard proper methods for insert/update/delete I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's already implemented. Take a look at the class code above. It has the countAffected method, so you use that after the query

```
$this->db->countAffected()
```

Which returns the number of affected rows

Comment: I searched the whole admin and catalog folders for the word "affected" and could find anything. I should of search the whole project, must of had my eyes closed to miss that though

Comment: `$this->db` is the `DB` class found in in `/system/library/db.php` which in turn calls the mysql class you referenced above and to be fair it's not immediately clear